# How do I get my icon to show up in Google email clients when I send programmatic emails from a Web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I have a Web application that sends emails programmatically.  When these emails arrive in a Google email client (like Inbox or Gmail), I'd like them to have a profile icon next to them that I have set.

Google offers a My Business service, but that is geared toward businesses that either have a physical storefront or deliver physical goods to customers, and my business does neither.

Thanks in advance.  A similar question was asked here but doesn't have an actionable response: [How do I get an icon in Google Inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229891/how-do-i-get-an-icon-in-google-inbox)

Comment: This has been answered in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229891/) you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. Get a google business email. You don't need a physical store or anything. I'm using it to deliver emails and you should too or else you will get a high spam rate.